# Broke default button's InputBinding to the Enter key

Tags: wpf

My WPF application has a form for performing searches of the database.  It has a `Button` that starts the search whose `IsDefault` property is set to true.  Normally, this allows the `Button's Click` event to fire when you press the enter key on the form.

The results of the search are shown in a Telerik `RadGridView`control.  Originally, if you double clicked on a row in the results, the program would take you to another tab and show you the details of the row you'd clicked on.  My boss asked me to modify the `RadGridView` so that when you press Enter, the control does the same thing.

I was able to achieve this by adding a custom command for displaying the details to my program and adding a `CommandBindings` section to the search control's XAML.I then added an `InputBindings` section to the `RadGridView's` XAML and everything works.  Except that pressing enter no longer raises the default `Button's Click` event:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CarSystem.CustomControls.Searcher"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:CarSystem.CustomControls"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CarSystem.ServiceModel;assembly=ViewModels"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Height="620"
             IsVisibleChanged="Searcher_IsVisibleChanged"
             Loaded="Searcher_Loaded"
             Width="990">

    <UserControl.CommandBindings>        
        <CommandBinding CanExecute="DisplayEditHotListEntry_CanExecute"  Command="cs:CarSystemCommands.DisplayEditHotListEntry"  Executed="DisplayEditHotListEntry_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding CanExecute="DisplayEditRecordDetails_CanExecute" Command="cs:CarSystemCommands.DisplayEditRecordDetails" Executed="DisplayEditRecordDetails_Executed" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>

    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource ContentBackground}"
              Name="LayoutRoot">

        . . .

        <telerik:RadGridView . . .>
            . . .
            <telerik:RadGridView.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{x:Static cs:CarSystemCommands.DisplayEditHotListEntry}" />
            </telerik:RadGridView.InputBindings>
        </telerik:RadGridView>

        <Button IsDefault="true" . . . />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The top of the form has a number of controls where search criteria are specified.  I'd like pressing the enter key while the focus is in one of these controls to fire off the default `Button's Click` event, and the new action when the focus is in the `RadGridView`.  How do I get this to work?

Comment: As always, some code samples would be helpful.  If you are wiring up your InputBindings on the datagrid, then it should only get fired when the datagrid has focus.  I have tested this and it works as expected.  I was able to have both the button's default click event fire and a datagrid's input binding command fire depending on what was focused.

Comment: Added exceprt from the XAML in question.